# Using webpack with a .html entry

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

How can I `webpack` a web app into an output `.html` file, starting from a traditional input `.html`?

Here is a simple starting point:

**index.html**

```html
<body>
  <output></output>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```js
import React from "react";
document.querySelector("output").innerText = React.version;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.html",
  output: {
    filename: "output.html"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /^index\.html$/, use: [
        {loader: "extract-loader"},
        {loader: "html-loader", options: {
          attrs: ["script:src"]
        }}
      ]}
    ]
  }
}
```

This results in `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` when processing `main.js`, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML as Webpack entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082181/html-as-webpack-entry-point)

Comment: @givanse Well, let's not mark a question from 20 months ago as duplicate of one from 4 hours ago.

Comment: parcel working exactly like that, maybe worth to checkout.

Comment: @felixmosh True but I'm using a few `webpack` loaders that don't have `parcel` equivalents.

Comment: from your error message, and the partial webpack config, I guess that you don't have a `babel-loader` for modern js files.

Comment: @felixmosh ES6 modules (`import`) are supported by `webpack` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same issue. My solution is: create empty js file as entry and you can remove that js from output path if don't need it.

Addtionally, if you use html-webpack-plugin, you can set inject to false, the html would not inject js.

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './views/cubes.njk', // your template
  filename: 'cubes.html',
  inject: false,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: "svg-inline-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./app/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
  ],
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development",
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**