# Why doesn't importing scripts from <script> tags work under html-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm developing a website with Webpack 5, `html-webpack-plugin`, and `html-loader`.

Here's my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>hello there</p>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="../script/index.ts">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.ts`:

```js
console.log('hi');
document.body.append('this isnt hmr but its not bad for a static site generator');
document.body.append('ree');
```

Here's the relevant section of my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = async (env) => {
  return {
    // ...
    module: {
      rules: [
        // ...
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          use: ['html-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // ...
      new HtmlPlugin({
        template: '../path/to/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
      })
    ],
    // ...
  };
};
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR in Error: webpack-internal:///608:2
>   document.body.append('this isnt hmr but its not bad for a static site generator');
>   ^
>   ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   
>   - 608:2 eval
>     webpack-internal:///608:2:1
>   
>   - index.html:21 Object.608
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:21:1
>   
>   - index.html:71 __webpack_require__
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:71:41  
>   - 673:3 eval
>     webpack-internal:///673:3:34
>   
>   - index.html:48 Object.673
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:48:1
>   
>   - index.html:71 __webpack_require__
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:71:41  
>   - index.html:81 
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:81:18  
>   - index.html:82 
>     /home/laptou/website/client/source/page/index.html:82:12  
>   - index.js:320 HtmlWebpackPlugin.evaluateCompilationResult
>     [client]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:320:28
> ```

Why is the code in my `index.ts` being evaluated, instead of just being bundled, and how do I make this stop happening?

Edits:

- I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063362/using-webpack-with-a-html-entry), but I feel my question is different because I am getting a different error. I already have a Babel loader in my chain, so all of the code should be perfectly digestible, plain JS.
- I have looked at [this question and its answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082181/html-as-webpack-entry-point), but I do not want to use Parcel because I could not get its glob imports to work correctly and consistently, and it does not have all of the features and community support that Webpack has.

Comment: Try importing with window.onload

Comment: @SaianshSingh How would that help? This error is occurring at compile time; it will just say that `window` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues in your webpack.config.js, and your index.html template.

Your template directly tries to include the index.ts, which is typescript.
But the plugin will inject the bundled script, so you shouldn't specify the script tag
yourself.
You have typescript in your project, but no rule specified with a loader for typescript.
You mention you are using 'html-webpack-plugin',
but the plugin you specify is spelled differently.

A final hint, on the error:
Whenever I've encountered 'docucument is not defined',
it has been because the webpack loader rules were configured inconsistently,
which causes webpack to execute the loaders on the wrong kinds of input,
which leads to weird 'the world is not defined!' kinds of errors.

Otherwise 'document is not defined' happens when clientside typescript/javascript
is erroneously included in a SSR(server-side-rendering) and/or nodeJS/server-side context.